# fastest way to create a list with differences of all entrys and the corresponding iterator in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm doing statistical science, and have this code snippet which consumes about 80% of my computing time. As the program will run for weeks, i want to make it as fast as possible. agg1 and agg2 are numpy arrays with 4 entries and length between 20 and 400

```
for i, j in itertools.product(xrange(agg1.shape[1]), xrange(agg2.shape[1])):
    iterator.append((i, j))
    particle_distances.append(agg1[0:2, i] - agg2[0:2, j])
```

does it pay off to i.e. filter my numpy arrays from the last entry (which is uninteresting here)? should i use `agg1.shape[1]` or better give it a variable name beforehand. The function which contains this code is called 4500 times. If there are any other faster approaches to achieve the differences of every list element and its corresponding iterator they are also welcome.

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f13fwqqhdlz7q0s/agg1?dl=1) is an example text file you can use. import with `numpy.loadtxt`.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you could provide some sample data which works with this function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computation can be concisely vectorized:

```
a = agg1[0:2, :].T
b = agg2[0:2, :].T
particle_distances = (a[:, None, :] - b[None, :, :]).reshape(-1, 2)
```

To retrieve the mapping of the indices you can call

```
idx1, idx2 = np.unravel_index(np.arange(agg1.shape[1] * agg2.shape[1]),
                              (agg1.shape[1], agg2.shape[1]))
```

This results in two arrays that correspond with the corresponding indices of `agg1` and `agg2`.

Let's compare performance:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from time_stats import compare_calls

agg1 = np.random.rand(100, 10)
agg2 = np.random.rand(100, 15)

def original(agg1, agg2):
    particle_distances = []
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(agg1.shape[1]), range(agg2.shape[1])):
        particle_distances.append(agg1[0:2, i] - agg2[0:2, j])
    return particle_distances

def prealloc(agg1, agg2):
    n = agg1.shape[1] * agg2.shape[1]
    particle_distances = np.empty((n, 2))
    for k, (i, j) in enumerate(itertools.product(range(agg1.shape[1]), range(agg2.shape[1]))):
        particle_distances[k, :] = agg1[0:2, i] - agg2[0:2, j]
    return particle_distances

def vectorized(agg1, agg2):
    a = agg1[0:2, :].T
    b = agg2[0:2, :].T
    particle_distances = (a[:, None, :] - b[None, :, :]).reshape(-1, 2)
    return particle_distances

r = compare_calls(['original(agg1, agg2)', 'prealloc(agg1, agg2)', 'vectorized(agg1, agg2)'], globals=globals())
r.print()
r.hist()

#   original(agg1, agg2) : 0.00038 s/call median, 0.00034 ... 0.00047 IQR
#   prealloc(agg1, agg2) : 0.00047 s/call median, 0.00041 ... 0.00068 IQR
# vectorized(agg1, agg2) : 6e-06 s/call median, 5.8e-06 ... 6.7e-06 IQR
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! however now the information which entry belongs to which combination seems to be lost. is there a way to retrieve this with the vectorized solution?

Comment: @michox, just don't reshape at the end. Then the row and column indices give you that information.

Comment: @michox you have several options.Dan's suggestion is one of them. You can also generate an index array manually or use the [`unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's slow because you're growing your lists inside a loop so it often has to move the lists around in memory as they grow too big. On option is to preallocate an array. If you use a 2D numpy array you can do away with `iterator` as it just become the indices:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
particle_distances = np.zeros((agg1.shape[1], agg2.shape[1],3))
for i, j in itertools.product(range(agg1.shape[1]), range(agg2.shape[1])):
    particle_distances[i,j,:] = agg1[0:2, i] - agg2[0:2, j]
```

However you can probably get more speedup and simplify your code by dropping the loop for a vectorized solution:

```
particle_distances  = np.transpose(np.expand_dims(agg1[0:2,:], axis=3), (1,2,0)) - np.transpose(np.expand_dims(agg2[0:2,:], axis=3), (2,1,0))
```

Here I've used `np.transpose` to change the shape of the matrices such that automatic broadcasting will do the job that `itertools.product` was doing for you. `np.expand_dims` is just to add a third dimension to each so that we can reshape them appropriately.

Comment: Lists use amortization to ensure that `list.append()` is very fast. I doubt that this is the real bottleneck. Also, you need to pass the shape as a single argument to `numpy.zeros`: `particle_distances = numpy.zeros((agg1.shape[1], agg2.shape[1]))`